# mkdocs navigation pointing to url docs

Tags: markdown, mkdocs

I currently off my documentation within the same directory as my mdocs.yml file, but I wonder if can add documentation from a different location possibly by URL?

```
site_name: 'School Supplies'
site_description: '5th grade school supplies for the summer'

plugins:
  - techdocs-core

nav:
  - Overview: index.md
  - English: school/english.md 
  - Math: school/math.md
  - Science: school/science.md
  - PE: school/pe.md
```

Rather than adding new documentation to my `school` directory, I want to add a new section from an external link such, as Github. For example:

```
nav:
  - Overview: index.md
  - English: school/english.md 
  - Math: school/math.md
  - Science: school/science.md
  - PE: school/pe.md
  - School Directory: https://github.com/education/classroom/blob/master/ROADMAP.md
```

I have tried changing blob from raw but didn't help as much. Is there a plugin or way to go about this?

Comment: MkDocs documents this [here](https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/configuration/#nav). In fact, what you have in your example is exactly what is documented. Have you actually tried it?

Comment: The reason I posted the question here is that when I post that URL it sends me directly to that site. I was wondering if I can use that .md file that's within that url

Comment: Ah I see. No, that is not possible. All md files must be local.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, so there is no work around this?